# Angular material table with rearrange rows and columns option

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, mat-table

I am trying to implement rearranging columns and rows in angular material table. I am able to achieve both separately. But having a hard time in implementing rearranging both rows and columns together in Angular material table.

I want to achieve [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z3cpj2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) angular material table.

Comment: I filed a feature request with Angular: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22287

Comment: You can see how another developer has been trying to solve this problem, over in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665859/is-it-possible-to-move-rows-and-columns-in-the-same-angular-material-table/66700301